# Amazon Web Services 2017_index

Tags: amazon-web-services

I used my mac terminal to access the following:

```
curl https://s3.amazonaws.com/irs-form-990/index_2017.csv > ~/Desktop/nhn2017.csv
```

I found the company I was interested in and then extracted the object_id of the company which I then used to get access to the company's 990 Form:

```
curl https://s3.amazonaws.com/irs-form-990/201702509349300000_public.xml > ~/Desktop/nhn2017form.xml
```

And here I found the object_id I extracted from the 2017_index file was not the company I was interested in but a completely unrelated company.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, here is the line in the excel file related to the company I was interested in:

Comment: 14835837 EFILE 391094315 201612 10/13/17 17:03 NEW HORIZONS NORTH INC 990 93493250006207 201702509349300000

Comment: The last entry is identified as the object_id

Comment: Okay ... it is the return_id but not the object_id and it is the object_id that is the unique identifier that identified the company I was interested in.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this appears to be a question about how to use the contents of the [Internal Revenue Service Form 990 public data set](https://aws.amazon.com/public-datasets/irs-990/), which happens to be made available by AWS.  It does not appear to be a programming question, or actually related to using AWS.

Comment: Sorry ... go ahead

Comment: Closing a question as off-topic generally requires consensus from the community and that comment, at the moment, only reflects my opinion.  It was intended to explain my rationale for casting a close vote as well as to clarify what you are asking about, since it was not clear from reading the question.  Others may disagree with my assessment.

Comment: Thanks ... I resolved it by using the url:

Comment: url: https://s3.amazonaws.com/irs-form-990/index_2017.json which then allowed me to pull the correct object_id which in turn allowed me to download the correct companies 990 Form.